# How to report historical unlocked but not a good question by current guidelines?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104690/any-good-tutorials-examples-for-the-spring-security-framework question. It was asked in 2008, but by current guidelines this question should most likely be closed.

My question is how to report these questions because I've seen similar questions that were protected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast a close vote ("Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."). It's a bad question, with very little historical/fluff value. You'll be able to do so pretty soon, once you gain 96 more reputation points.

Until you get to the 3000 point mark, you could just use a flag instead.